# WebSocket suddenly refuses connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io

For my project I needed a VPS, so I bought one on DigitalOcean. I installed MongoDB, Laravel and the whole thing runs on Nginx.

Earlier today I asked a question about a timer and the advice was to use WebSockets. According to the comment, the best approach was to use NodeJS with Socket.io. And so I did.

I followed [this](http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/) tutorial here (locally) and had absolutely no problems at all on localhost.

So my next step was to upload the code to my webserver and combine it with Laravel. I had some problems making connections, but after I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366232/nodejs-and-php-laravel-integration-for-socket-io-live-chat) Stackoverflow post, it finally worked. The server was sending a Date-object and the timer on the screen was updating realtime.

But it only worked when I manually started the script through the `node` terminal-command. So I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial on DigitalOcean where you use PM2 to keep running the script, even when I close the terminal/log out of my VPS. Everything was working fine and the timer was still updating and I was actually very surprised that I didn't run into that many problems..

..until 5 minutes later. All of a sudden, the WebSocket stopped working. Maybe I had made a typo without realising, maybe the server noticed some change in the code that I didn't. I have no clue, but when I look in the developers console, it says:

```
GET http://<my-domain-ip>:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LF8I2CO net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Of course, I googled a lot and applied all sorts of changes to my code according to (mostly) Stackoverflow answers, but now I'm really running short on ideas and have absolutely no idea why my code is not working.

The server.js file:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch(path) {
        case '/' :
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            response.end();
            break;
        case '/socket.html' :
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function (error, data) {
                if(error) {
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("Oops, this doesn't exist - 404");
                    response.end();
                } else {
                    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
                    response.write(data, 'utf8');
                    response.end();
                }
            });
            break;
        default :
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("Oops, this doesn't exist - 404");
            response.end();
            break;
    }
});

server.listen(8080, '<private ip>');
console.log('Server running at http://<private ip>:8080/');


var listener = io.listen(server);

listener.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit('date', {'date' : new Date()});
    });

});
```

(I had to set a private IP according to the DigitalOcean tutorial, so Nginx could make it work).

The Javascript code on the client's side:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>

                    <script>
                        var baseURL               = getBaseURL(); // Call function to determine it
                        var socketIOPort          = 8080;
                        var socketIOLocation      = baseURL + socketIOPort; // Build Socket.IO location
                        var socket                = io(socketIOLocation);

                        //Build the user-specific path to the socket.io server, so it works both on 'localhost' and a 'real domain'
                        function getBaseURL()
                        {
                            baseURL = location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + ":" + location.port;
                            return baseURL;
                        }

                        socket.on('date', function (data) {
                            $('#date').text(data.date.getHours() + ':' + data.date.getMinutes() + ':' + data.date.getSeconds());
                        })
                    </script>
```

If I remember correctly, I also set some options like `proxy_pass` and `Upgrade $upgrade`, but I can't remember where I read that / which file I applied that to, but as far as I know, those options are set correctly.

Does someone know where the problem lies? Because I'm really running out of ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hosting companies often have ways of "managing" long running connections to preserve their resources.  One possibility is that your hosting infrastructure needs to be specifically configured for a long running webSocket connection so nginx (or some other piece of networking equipment) doesn't automatically kill it after some period of time.  This is not something that is generic to all hosting - it is specific to the configuration of your particular VPS at your particular hosting company so you will have to get any guidance on this topic from them.

Comment: Of possible help: http://nolanlawson.com/2013/05/31/web-sockets-with-socket-io-node-js-and-nginx-port-80-considered-harmful/

Comment: I changed the port to 443 according to your mentioned article and it immediately worked! I also contacted DigitalOcean and they said that the WebSockets are supposed to keep working and that the problem was probably some configuration errors on my Nginx server. But the WebSockets are running a few hours now without any problems, so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hosting companies often have ways of "managing" long running
>   connections to preserve their resources. One possibility is that your
>   hosting infrastructure needs to be specifically configured for a long
>   running webSocket connection so nginx (or some other piece of
>   networking equipment) doesn't automatically kill it after some period
>   of time. This is not something that is generic to all hosting - it is
>   specific to the configuration of your particular VPS at your
>   particular hosting company so you will have to get any guidance on
>   this topic from them.
>
> Of possible help:
>   http://nolanlawson.com/2013/05/31/web-sockets-with-socket-io-node-js-and-nginx-port-80-considered-harmful/

I changed:

```
server.listen(8080, <private ip>);
```

to:

```
server.listen(443);
```

And:

```
var socketIOPort = 8080;
```

to:

```
var socketIOPort = 443;
```

and the WebSockets were working instantly, thanks to [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00)!